# How can I make condition for class of x-jet-dialog-modal?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-jetstream

With  laravel 8.68 and livewire 2.7 opening modal dialog (which can be used in many cases) I want
to change background color/color depending on parameter.
I try to change class in <x-jet-dialog-modal definition like :

```
<x-jet-dialog-modal wire:model="confirmActionModalProfileFormVisible"
                    class=" z-50 bg-opacity-100 @if($confirm_action_profile_modal_color === 'danger') personal_danger_text @else personal_text @endif">
```

But That does not work, and in browser's inspection I see that class in <x-jet-dialog-modal is not rendered,

I try to use alpinejs :

```
<x-jet-dialog-modal wire:model="confirmActionModalProfileFormVisible"
                    :class=" 'z-50 bg-opacity-100 ' + ( '{{$confirm_action_profile_modal_color }}' == 'danger' ? 'personal_danger_text' : 'personal_text' ) ">
```

But error was raised :

```
A non-numeric value encountered (View: my-template.blade.php)
```

Can I make condition for class of <x-jet-dialog-modal ?

**UPDATED # 1:**
Yes, I have jetstream views published , and I have file resources/views/vendor/jetstream/components/dialog-modal.blade.php,
which have default content :

```
@props(['id' => null, 'maxWidth' => null, 'class' => null])

<x-jet-modal :id="$id" :maxWidth="$maxWidth" {{ $attributes }}  class="{{ !empty($class) ? $class : ''}}">
    <div class="px-6 py-4 {{ !empty($class) ? $class : ''}}">
        <div class="text-lg">
            {{ $title }}
        </div>

        <div class="mt-4">
            {{ $content }}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="px-6 py-4 text-right {{ !empty($class) ? $class : ' bg-gray-100'}}">
        {{ $footer }}
    </div>
</x-jet-modal>
```

As I inheret my modal file from it I wonder in which way have I to edit definition of <x-jet-dialog-modal to pass
conditional class ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

you have to publish jetstream views, then edit the file **dialog-modal.blade.php** and use the slot attributes.
[Laravel Blade #Slot Attributes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#slot-attributes)

If you want to change something from the modal itself, you would have to edit **modal.blade.php**

Edit the following line:

```html
    <div x-show="show" class="mb-6 bg-white rounded-lg overflow-hidden shadow-xl transform transition-all sm:w-full {{ $maxWidth }} sm:mx-auto">
```

And do attribute merge [Laravel Blade #Deafault/Merged Attributes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#default-merged-attributes)

Comment: please look at UPDATED # 1

Answer (score 0):

another way will be to edit published JetStream modal window view (resources/views/vendor/jetstream/componets/modal.blade.php) and add `{{$attributes['class']}}` in class values. After that you can add any custom class or condition when including jetstream modal:

```
<x-jet-dialog-modal wire:model="myCustomModal" maxWidth="md" class="flex items-center my-custom-class">
```

and this will be applied on your modal. And now you should be able to use your conditions as well:

```
<x-jet-dialog-modal wire:model="myCustomModal" maxWidth="md" class="flex items-center my-custom-class @if($confirm_action_profile_modal_color === 'danger') personal_danger_text @else personal_text @endif">
```

nice example can be seen here:
https://floyk.com/en/post/how-to-use-laravel-jetstream-livewire-modal
or here:
https://floyk.com/en/post/livewire-5-ways-to-call-and-update-value-on-click